# How to join 'n' number of files in ordered way efficiently using paste/join or linux or perl?

Tags: linux, join, paste, memory-efficient

Thousands of files ends with *.tab. First column in each file is a header. Every file have their own headers (so they are different). I don't mind to have one header from any file.

Number of rows are equal in all the files and so have an order. My desired output have the same order.

### Example files in a directory

```
test_1.tab
test_2.tab
.
.
.
.
test_1990.tab
test_2000.tab
```

### test_1.tab

```
Pro_01 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 .....0
Pro_02 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 .....1
Pro_03 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 .....1
.
.
.
Pro_200 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0  .....0
```

### test_2000.tab

```
Pro_1901 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 .....0
Pro_1902 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 .....1
Pro_1903 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 .....1
.
.
.
Pro_2000 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0  .....0
```

### desired output

```
Pro_01 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 ..... 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
Pro_02 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 ..... 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
Pro_03 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 ..... 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
.
.
.
Pro_200 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0  ..... 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

### My code

```
for i in *.tab/; do paste allCol.tab <(cut -f 2- "$i") > itermediate.csv; mv intermediate.csv allCol.tab ; done

paste <(cut -f1 test1.tab) allCol.tab > final.tab
rm allCol.tab
```

It takes a quite time like 3 hrs. Which is a better way? 
Also, is there any other command to cross check this output file vs all input files? like diff or wc?

Comment: re: crosschecks, if anything failed, either the number of lines or the number of fields in the last line will be wrong. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
#!/bin/bash    

TMP=tmp
mkdir "$TMP"
RESULT=result

#read each file and append the contents of each line in them
#to a new file for each line in the tmp directory 
for f in *.tab; do
    i=1
    while read -r l; do
        echo "$l" >> "$TMP"/"$i"
        ((i++))
    done < <(cut -f2- "$f")
done

#integrate each file in tmp dir into a single line of the $RESULT file
exec 1>>$RESULT    
for f in "$TMP"/*; do
    while read -r l; do
        printf '%s\t' "$l"
    done < <(cat "$f")
    echo
done

rm -r "$TMP"
```

This algorithm can be split on a number of processors and the task would get done faster.

You can also add to it things like checking if `$TMP` was created successfully.

Comment: Is it "$f" instead of "bar.sh"? Anyhow, second section (integrating tmp files) not working. I stick to my code which I mentioned above. But how can I check (crosscheck) that everything went well?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated it. I consider it a Bash script now. I'll think of a testing script and will let you know.

Comment: The first stage would be much faster with awk (which supports implicit caching of file descriptors), if the number of lines will fit within the FD table. Beyond that, I've got a bunch of various kibitzing about variable case, reliance on non-POSIX `echo` functionality; &c., but don't know how welcome that would be at the moment.

Comment: I'm an intermediate level amateur, don't know `awk` well, and don't have much to say. But you can use my code in your answer if you like. I could change my answer to a wiki, but don't think this is the right question for this kind of musing either.

Comment: @perlbeginner As for testing, I don't think there's any ready solution for it. You can use a part of the production script for testing single lines, with something like `tail -n"$lineno" | head -n1` for, say the first line, the last line, and one in the middle, against the result file (with the same construct).

Comment: I edited the last answer a few time, just in case you got lost.

Comment: And you can check the number of lines in the result.

Comment: @tomas: looks nice. but the first column from every file is still in the concatenated output. I want to have only one of the first column (say, from the first file) in the final output. Not necessary to have the first columns of all the files, though they are different.  why cut -f2- is not working properly?

Comment: This script should skip all of them. The only explanation I have is that you are getting mistaken with some old output at the beginning of the result file. If possible, run the script for a few seconds and then check the temp files in $TMP. (Remove the dir after the test.)

Comment: how the first field from every file is included already in the output files of $TMP/* ?

Comment: That could be possible if you run a script that does it and terminated it before it removed the $TMP. But given $TMP doesn't exist, if you run it and see the first field is not in the file, then you know the script is ok. Now, the $RESULT file might contain the first field if you created it with another script that passes the first field. My script only appends to the $RESULT file, without truncating it, so whatever was there before, stays as it was.

Comment: ok. that means, i paste a first column from one of my files to the $RESULT file, which will be the final RESULT file. Am i right? In that case, the order of the $RESULT (rows especially) is the same like all input files?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And each file in the $TMP represents a corresponding line. So, $TMP/3 is a file for line 3. And $l line in $TMP/3 has what was found on line 3 in the file nr $l. Then in the second part of the script they get integrated, ie. all the lines of each file become a single line in the result. So file 3 becomes line 3 in the result.

Comment: Nice.. works faster than the code I mentioned in my query. with correction: (cut -f2- "$f") will give exactly from column 2. cut -f2- -d " " "$f" gives me from the column 1. Also, echo -n "$l " is not completely tab delimited output at the end. rather echo -n "$l     " gives a tab delimited output at the end ?

Comment: Please consider `printf '%s\t' "$l"` vs an `echo -n` with a tab. The former is POSIX-specified, the latter is explicitly undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function is a good tool. As a first cut -- short, but simple:

```
pasteAll() {
  first=$1; shift
  case $# in
    0) cut -f 2- "$first" ;;
    *) paste <(cut -f 2- "$first") <(pasteAll "$@") ;;
  esac
}

set -- *.tab    
paste <(cut -f 1 "$1") <(pasteAll "$@")
```

Checking that all files and lines were included -- if every input file contains an identical number of lines -- is as simple as checking the output file's line count and the number of columns in its last line.

Comment: it may be good for (less number) files having less number of columns!! but in my case it is thousands of files, most of them having several hundreds of columns. System frozen!

Comment: If the "frozen" system is moving data through the pipes, it'll finish eventually. Yes, your interactive processes are outnumbered in the process table, so they won't get any substantial amount of CPU time, so you'll lose interactivity, but that doesn't mean nothing is happening. The only case where this is *actually* not going to finish, as opposed to just slowing things down for a bit, is if it's driving your system into swap; monitoring `vmstat` can track whether that's actually happening.

Comment: If you stripped the headers off your input files, by the way, a **much** more efficient approach would be trivial.

Comment: Of course, it is working but due to larger number of columns per each file, it gets restarted at some extent. And not finished. There are no headers in all the input files..

Comment: re: "headers", I'm referring to the leftmost columns you're removing with `cut`.

Comment: ...and please explain "gets restarted". It's called recursively, that's the point, but those recursive invocations are working on different data than their parents are; there are no two completely identical processes working on identical data at any point.

Comment: After I run this code, I have seen (from "top" command) thousands of bash process at a time but only one cut/paste process. Slowly my machine hanged and restarted. I checked this twice. I don't know exactly why it got hanged and restarted?! For your information, there are 2345 files constitute 2088762 columns

Comment: Yes, the thousands of processes is normal and expected. "hanged and restarted" means what, **exactly**? By "restart" do you mean a reboot? I could see that happen if there's a userspace watchdog that isn't getting petted on time, but in general that's not expected behavior (and there should be logs to explain it).

Comment: ...anyhow, I might at some point write a two-phase implementation -- if we strip off the first column before starting the recursive code, an implementation using only O(log2 n) processes is possible; for your 2345 input files, that would mean only 12 or so. (This is why I was saying that the column headers make this much less efficient).

Comment: Yes, i mean reboot.

Comment: Ahh. Unless you have a watchdog configured, that's actually a kernel bug -- even in an out-of-memory condition, the kernel is supposed to be able to kill userspace processes as necessary to preserve its own operation -- but unless you're inclined to go investigate it (ie. figure out which drivers you're using that aren't handling failed allocations properly), that isn't knowledge that does much good. If I get a chance, I'll draft up the O(log2 n) at some point today.